# can't build `Hello world` cordova project with Netbeans because of proxy

Tags: git, cordova, netbeans

I can't build `Hello world` cordova project with Netbeans.

I have to use a company firewall to access internet. It is an IP address with port 81. I use Windows 8.1.

I configured proxy in npm, git and netbeans. And while building I have an error (full log from output window):

```
cordova.cmd plugins 
cordova.cmd -d plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git"
Fetching plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git" via git clone
Running command: "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clone --depth=1 https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git C:\Users\KORALE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1444040988889
Command finished with error code 128: c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe clone,--depth=1,https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git,C:\Users\KORALE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1444040988889
CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git via git.
Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
    Error: c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe: Command failed with exit code 128 Error output:
Cloning into 'C:\Users\KORALE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1444040988889'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git/': Failed to connect to git-wip-us.apache.org port 443: Timed out
    at C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:88:33
    at _rejected (C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\KoralewskiP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:336:13)
```

Moreover when I run the command

```
"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clone --depth=1 https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git C:\Users\KORALE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1444040988889
```

from cmd it works well.

I also set HTTP_PROXY environment variable and restarted Netbeans but it hasn't help either.

Comment: Did you try the same with HTTPS_PROXY?

Comment: @Harish - I tried and it has helped. I'd like to mark your answer as accepted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable as well.